# Python3 Python 3 how to use result from randint to evaluate an array and pull the correct choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random, evaluate

I am using Python3.

I am trying to evaluate "skill checks" for my game, and I want to create a function, that can be evluated for all, standard skill rolls.

I'm only at the most basic level for now, so, I'm just trying to create the function itself, then later, I want to use my database, but for now:

1. My game uses success "thresholds", which,
2. when I'm rolling dice (it was a pen-n-paper game, but, handling the dice rolls takes forever), takes the results -
3. compares it to a range of numbers, and tells you how well you failed/succeeded.

Desired flow:

1. 1-100 is rolled.
2. [ignored for this question]: if a 96+ is rolled, roll again and add the results.
3. List/Array/Dictionary/Whatever (later DataBase) is checked and the appropriate type of success is generated.

What I don't know are:

1. How do I build this list?  Should this be a dictionary, a list, or a tuple?
2. What do I do once I have generated a random number?  What do I do with that number in order to evaluate my list of thresholds?

Thresholds and their Ranges:

```
Total Failure: 1-25,
Partial Failure: 26-49,
Partial Success: 50-74,
Success: 75-100,
Significant Success: 101-149,
Astounding Success: 150-199,
Epic Success: 200-249,
Legendary: 250+
```

Comment: Can you add a step-by-step example?

Comment: So the step-by-step (and thank you ehacinorn) is as follows:
- instantiate function
- function contains the types of success in an if/elif format
- setup variable called skill_check, which is a random integer between 1 and 100.
- skill_result calls the function and feeds-in the results of the random integer.
- a print statement with a format, tells me both the number and the type of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a data structure but a function.

```
def type_of_success(n):
    # input: integer random number rolled
    # output: string

    if not isinstance(n, int) or n < 1:
        raise Exception('Not a valid number')

    if n < 26:
        return 'Total Failure'
    elif n < 51:
        return 'Partial Failure'
    # etc
```

Comment: This is what I used to pull the results that I wanted.

`skill_check = random.randint(1,101)`
`skill_result = type_of_success(skill_check)`
`print(f'{skill_check}\n{skill_result}')`